# (Unity) Network.Instantiate doesn't get called on all clients

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, instantiation, multiplayer, unity-networking

I'm working on a small networking project and have been having trouble instantiating objects over the network. I have no issue when one person joins the server...I get issues when a second person joins - that second person is only instantiated on the first person's client, and the other person is not seen in the second player's client. I know the Network.Instatiate is supposed to get called on all clients, even when they join later, but it's just not happening for me...Take a look:

```
private void SpawnPlayer()
{
    GameObject spawnPoints = GameObject.Find("Spawns");
    GameObject player = (GameObject)Network.Instantiate(playerPrefab, spawnPoints.transform.GetChild(Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.transform.childCount - 1)).transform.position, Quaternion.identity,0);
    //This is just to assign the current player to the shoot button so it knows which one to shoot from
    if (player.GetComponent<NetworkView>().viewID.isMine)
    {
        EventTrigger trigger = shootButton.GetComponent<EventTrigger>();
        EventTrigger.Entry entry = new EventTrigger.Entry();
        entry.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerDown;
        currentPlayer = player.GetComponent<Player>();
        UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction<BaseEventData> call = new UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction<BaseEventData>(ShootEventMethod);
        entry.callback.AddListener(call);
        trigger.triggers.Add(entry);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a client-side issue. Whenever the second player connects, you should call another function that gets each player in the server and spawns them in the second player's view. A function similar to `SpawnPlayer()`.